# How to insert an animated image into an email body only for Outlook 2013?

Tags: email, outlook

I am trying to insert a .gif into the body of an email, and have it display in Outlook.

I have tried by going Insert → Pictures, but it converts the .gif into a static image form even though the original is animated.

What can I do to get an animated image in Outlook?

Comment: Hi Scott. Are you embedding the gif as part of the email, or using an `img` tag to display the gif? Can you supply some sample code of what you are doing? It may also be helpful for you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Richard, I am just using the following image tag:- <img src="images/moving.gif" />

Comment: Richard, just making a standard HTML email as follows:- 

          <tr>
             <td><img src="images/s.gif" /></td>
   </tr>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft considers `.gif` images to be active content, and for security reasons, Outlook does not allow active content to run in messages.

> All Outlook versions after 2007
>
> There is no support for animated gif-files when composing or reading an email. If you want to see the animation you’ll need to open the message in a browser.
>
> To do this, double click the message to open it in its own window. Then choose (Other) Actions-> View in Browser. This will open the message in Internet Explorer.
>
> Note: Even though the gif-file will not animate while composing, when the recipient receives your message in a mail client that does support gif-animation, the gif-animation will still work.
>
> [Source](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/107)

So what this is saying is that Outlook will show the first frame of a `.gif` image. If you add a `.gif` using compose email in Outlook, and send the email to a device that can display `.gif`, say an iPhone, the `.gif` will animate on there.

In Outlook versions before 2007 they have limited support. This is because in 2007 Microsoft moved from using Internet Explorer (which can display `.gif`) to render the emails, to Microsoft Word (which blocks `.gif`).

Because of this change, Outlook does not support a lot of the latest HTML5 standards, including the HTML5 animations. So there is currently no way for Outlook (desktop at least) to show any type of animation.

Comment: could we do a html5 background in our email body? if so i feel like using html5 without gif we can have the html5 be the animation.

Answer (score 3):

HTML messages are rendered by Word, not IE in Outlook. Word does not support animated GIFs.

**Update (March 2019)**: animated GIFs are now supported by Outlook.
See https://www.msoutlook.info/question/animated-gif-support

Comment: what about a html5 animation? non gif animation?

Comment: That won't work either as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem boils down to how Outlook renders GIFs.

> Since 2007, Outlook began to use Microsoft Word as it’s text editor.
>   Word cannot read HTML elements in your emails meaning that all GIFs
>   you include as you write an email, or GIFs received in an email from
>   someone else, will display as a still image of the first frame of that
>   GIF.
>
> In 2013, Outlook moved to a new text editor similar to word.
>   Unfortunately the same HTML issues existed within this editor, so
>   there was no change for users.

[Source](https://www.crossware.co.nz/blog/issues-with-gifs-in-outlook/)

[Microsoft Office FAQ](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/the-animated-graphic-in-my-e-mail-message-doesn-t-work-a5e8a2a3-9d86-4203-8920-c88cb8739e34)

As a work-around, it is possible to conditional logic to show an animated gif to non-outlook users, and a specific static image for outlook users:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<img class="outlookcomIMG" src="ANIMATED.gif">
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<img src="STATIC.jpg">
<![endif]-->
```

The first block of code will show an animated gif, while the second will show a static image in Outlook. Although not ideal, it does allow you to create call to actions that look effective in both environments.

[Solution from Email on acid](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/gifs-and-outlook-what-can-we-do/)

Comment: Thats exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!